# making comma separated string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, listagg

How can we convert `12345` into `1,2,3,4,5` .

I can do the reverse by using replace command and i can replace comma by null. But I am not able to do the above. Could you please help on the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed template with consecutive, one-digit numbers like `1234` or `12345` or `123456789`

you may try the following by using `listagg` function of Oracle :

```
with t as
(
 select '12345' as col from dual 
)
select listagg(level,',') within group (order by level) as str
   from t
connect by level <= length(col);

STR
---------
1,2,3,4,5
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo 1***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c30b/10)

*OR*

For more generalized solution, use the following :

```
with t as
(
 select 'abcde' as col from dual 
)
select listagg(substr(col,level,1),',') within group (order by level) as str
   from t
connect by level <= length(col);

STR
---------
a,b,c,d,e
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo 2***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c30b/15)

Comment: hi @Barbaros.. ur query's output is limited to the length of the string passed and will be in integer format of 1234...

Comment: Query should be more generic in the sense that any value passed should be broken into comma separated list.

Comment: @ihm017 sure, you're right, and I already mentioned about the constraints `consecutive, one-digit numbers`, i.e. if OP wanna have a special case.

Comment: @ihm017 I think, now the query is as you mentioned, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
rtrim(regexp_replace('12345', '([0-9])', '\1,'), ',')
```

The `rtrim()` is necessary because the last digit is also replaced.

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=724adecda03305b281ad3bf0f380ca58

Comment: Since the title mentioned making a string, I would use `'(.)'` as the regex.